# Why will my ajax call fire twice ?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this script that triggers the ajax call, it will fire and return the correct data from the database, and then all of a sudden will fire again all in all leaving the error message. It works but there is certainly some bug.

I've been trying to identify it, yet with little to no success.

Here is code:

```
$(document).on('click',"#frcode_sendagain_button",function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/ajax_frcode_sendagain.php', 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: ({email_ajax: window.global_email_var}),
    success: function(data){
        var feedback_from_database = data;
        $('#frcode_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17"});
        $('#frcode_feedback').html('Авторизационный код выслан');
    },
    error: function(){
        $('#frcode_feedback').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000"});
        $('#frcode_feedback').html('Серверная ошибка');
    }
});
});
```

php script

```
session_start();
include('mysql/database.php');
$email_from_jq=$_POST['email_ajax'];
$create_pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email_from_jq";
$query = $create_pdo->prepare($sql_query);
$query->bindParam(':email_from_jq', $email_from_jq);
$query->execute();
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row_from_query=$query->fetch();
if (!empty($row_from_query['frcode'])){
    $messagetosend="<font size=\"2\" color=\"#347C17\" face=\"Tahoma\"><strong>Приветствуем нового пользователя проекта 'Фаворит'!</strong></font><br><font size=\"2\"      color=\"#1F2320\" face=\"Tahoma\">Для того, чтобы начать пользоваться нашим сайтом, вам нужно будет ввести авторизационный код.<br>Ваш авторизационный код: <font size=\"2\" color=\"#347C17\" face=\"Tahoma\"><strong>".$row_from_query['frcode']."</strong></font><br>Этот процесс проводится в целях борьбы со спамом и его предотвращения.<br>С уважением,<br>Проект 'Фаворит'.</font>";
$mailheader='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$mailheader.="X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
$mailheader.="From: Фаворит <happyregistration@favorit.kz>";
mail($row_from_query['email'],"Авторизация на проекте 'Фаворит'",$messagetosend,$mailheader);
$array_to_json=array("action" => "sent");
    echo json_encode($array_to_json);}
```

Comment: Please check the network tab in your web inspector. Does it actually show 2 duplicate requests?

Comment: It does, but they are different. The first one has the content-length, the second one does not. So, the second request is empty.

Comment: What is response of first request? It could be that you received 301 Moved Permanently and new request has been triggered...

Comment: maybe browser plugins involved?

Comment: Hmm interesting, is there any other elements that could cause event bubbling?

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to browser plugins. And it is 200. THere aren't any elements that I know of. What else could be a potential reason?

Comment: Can you show your html? The PHP is not relevant here. There **must** be some sort of event bubbling.

Comment: Is it possible that you're binding the click function multiple times?  Try clearing the click event with unbind() before binding it.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you defined the event listener 2 times, try this debug code:

```
alert('init');//just to see where it is called
$(document).off('click',"#frcode_sendagain_button"); //removes previous  .on definitions
$(document).on('click',"#frcode_sendagain_button",function(){
...
}
```

This should help you to detect if the problem is duplicated event binding.